# Accessing roboearth database

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was able to retrieve bottle and book dataset from the roboearth.
But it was through some wild search. Cant't i browse through the database and download the objects.

I feel that the objects dataset is pretty fine as they are segmented and in the form of pcd files. It is very useful to experiment on the object recognition stuff with such kind of dataset. So is there any other way to access the datasets that are in pcd forms and ready to use. Are there any other places to get the datasets?

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12559/accessing-roboearth-database/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can browse the object models available in the database via the [web interface](http://api.roboearth.org/): move the mouse pointer over "Search", click on "Objects". Then click on the upper "Search" button without entering anything to see all object models.

HTH,
Daniel

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-28**:
oh... :) thanks i missed it